# Array of structs init and getter

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm quite new to Solidity development and I'm struggling with structs for now.
I followed several examples but can't get a way to add a struct to my array of structs. My last try is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Iceicebaby {

struct Parcel {
  string state;
  string flavour;
  uint256 weight;
  address holder;
}

Parcel[] public parcels;

function newParcel(string _flavour, uint256 _weight) public {
  parcels.length++;
  parcels[parcels.length-1].state="ORDERED";
  parcels[parcels.length-1].flavour=_flavour;
  parcels[parcels.length-1].weight=_weight;
  parcels[parcels.length-1].holder=msg.sender;
}

function getParcelsCount () view public returns (uint){
  return parcels.length;
}

function getParcel(uint256 index) view public returns (string, string, uint256, address) {
  return (parcels[index].state, parcels[index].flavour, parcels[index].weight ,parcels[index].holder);
}}
```

For now I get :

myInstance.order("Flavour",1) :

> { tx: '0xfad42f92c158557c46496df3fd104d7a09899e641e66748e57b03262f4f5fc62',
>     receipt:
>      { transactionHash: '0xfad42f92c158557c46496df3fd104d7a09899e641e66748e57b03262f4f5fc62',
>        transactionIndex: 0,
>        blockHash: '0xc39e94e8e9e9a26fd372ad12d2eba4a72f06251d2f29c4a344cd9e58849d9e49',
>        blockNumber: 17,
>        gasUsed: 22168,
>        cumulativeGasUsed: 22168,
>        contractAddress: null,
>        logs: [],
>        status: 1 },
>     logs: [] }

myInstance.getParcelsCount()

> BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }

myInstance.getParcel(0) or myInstance.getParcel(1)

> [ '', '', BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }, '0x' ]

I tried several other solutions, mapping the structure and stuff like this but can't deal with this thing which should be easy, no?

Also, I can't find how to properly debbug and display logs, is there any standards for this ? I'm using truffle and a local ganache network.

Thanks !

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Remix. Have you tried it there? Note that `getParcel()` is redundant... it does the exact same thing as the `parcels()` getter that's automatically generated because `parcels` is a `public` state variable.

Comment: Note that when you get back a `BigNumber`, you can use `toString()` or `toNumber()` to more easily see the value.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. Indeed it works well in Remix but parcels(0) still gives me an empty structure, is my array system with indexes correct ?

Comment: Are you saying `parcels(0)` in Remix doesn't work for you? It works fine for me with the exact code copy/pasted from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the transaction is not having enough gas to executing the code to store the data.
By default `web3` sends 90000 gas (`needs confirmation`), which is not enough for the transaction you are trying to execute.
Change the following line of code with an extra optional parameter. Here I am providing **150000** gas to the transaction. You can have an easy estimation how much gas is required for a transaction by looking at transaction logs of [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org).

> myInstance.order("Flavour",1)

```
myInstance.order("Flavour",1, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 150000})
```